# Bundle UMD module that depends on external library with browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, browserify

I am implementing a module which supposed to work in NodeJS and Browser (AMD/non-AMD) env.

Simplified version of it looks like that:

```javascript
var Backbone = require('backbone');

module.exports = Backbone.Model.extend({...});
```

But I do not see how to make it work for all envs.

- If i use global Backbone (without `require`) it will not work in NodeJS env
- If i use require and exclude backbone from the bundle (using `--exclude backbone`) - it will not work in browser non-AMD (Error: can't find module `backbone`)

Is it possible to generate UMD module which will:

- use `require('backbone')` in browser (AMD) / NodeJS env
- `window.Backbone` in browser (non-AMD)?

Answer (score 0):

The umd package has a mode for jQuery plugins that work in non-AMD, AMD, or CommonJS environment. The example is jquery, but 
you could adapt it for your own namespace module that's not jquery.

https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/jqueryPluginCommonjs.js

One way I have handled this in the past is to build my standalone bundles for the plugin using `require('namespace')` but use a stub that follows the pattern linked above in place of the real module.

```
bundle
  .require('./namespace-stub', {expose: 'namespace'})
  .require('plugin', {entry: true});
```

Where `namespace-stub.js` is a tiny module following the pattern linked above, but instead of invoking a function with namespace (taken from either AMD, CommonJS, or globals), it can just export it.

In other words, you build the standalone bundle for the plugins by substituting a module in place of the main library package which actually just looks for and discovers the real library from wherever it happens to be available.